How to prohibit Jenkins to send emails to irrelevant Git users
I have a Jenkins job that uses Extended E-mail Notification plugin to send info after build done. I set $BUILD_USER_EMAIL as recipient and it basically works. But... When resulting build page looks like this

I found in logs that Jenkins for some reason tries to send email to user that triggered the build AND ALSO to each author of listed git changes:
Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Not sending mail to unregistered user jake@best.com because your SCM claimed this was associated with a user ID ‘jake' which your security realm does not recognize; you may need changes in your SCM plugin
Not sending mail to unregistered user john@best.com because your SCM claimed this was associated with a user ID ‘john' which your security realm does not recognize; you may need changes in your SCM plugin
Not sending mail to unregistered user jim@best.com because your SCM claimed this was associated with a user ID ‘jim' which your security realm does not recognize; you may need changes in your SCM plugin
Sending email to: sammy@best.com jim@best.com
Finished: SUCCESS

and so irrelevant people receives the email... How to avoid this?

Finally found the problem. By default in "Advanced Settings" there is a "Developers" option which should be deleted.

